# Database model with shared and platform specific data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a personal project (addon) for World of Warcraft related to achievements.

I set up an EF database to manager all the data I input. When I started I was only targeting 1 platform (expansion, client). But over the past 2 year a 2nd platform needed to be supported so I had to split up some data. Now with a 3rd one on the horizon I feel like my current data model is not sufficient and scalable towards the future.

An example class is the `Category` class. Most data is shared between the clients but like the `FunctionValue` and `IsLegacy` are platform specific. I have multiple classes doing the same thing so it's definitely a global issue in my data structure atm.

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Function Function { get; set; }
    public string FunctionValueRetail { get; set; }
    public string FunctionValueWrathClassic { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsLegacy { get; set; }
    public bool IsLegacyWrathClassic { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsActiveWrathClassic { get; set; } = true;
    public bool CanMerge { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlwaysVisible { get; set; }
    public bool HasFlexibleData { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ObservableCollection<CategoryAchievement> CategoryAchievements { get; set; } = new();
}
```

My question is, if this is an ok design or if there are better ways to tackle this? I need shared data but also platform specific data.

One thing I can think about is of having a shared table and a table for platform specific stuff. That would make 3 tables `CategoryShared`, `CategoryRetail` and `CategoryWrathClassic` with the last 2 having the `FunctionValue` and `IsLegacy` fields.